# Irreducibility of an explicit complex projective variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables, computational-geometry, computer-algebra, prime-ideals

Let $Y\subset \mathbb P^n_\mathbb C$ be a subvariety defined by a series of homogeneous polynomials $f_1, \ldots, f_t$. Is there an effective way to determine the irreducibility of $Y$ as an algebraic variety?

It seems to me that computers are not able to do such calculations since we are in $\mathbb C$ (compare to the possibility to determine the irreducibility if the base field was $\mathbb Q$).

In particular, the variety that interests me is the surface $\Sigma$ in $\mathbb P^4$ (using $x_1, \ldots, x_5$ as coordinates) defined by
$$ x_3^2 + 2x_1x_4 - 4x_2x_4 +2x_2x_5 - 4x_1x_5 = 0$$
and
$$ x_4(x_1^2 - 2x_2^2) + x_5(x_2^2 - 2x_1^2) = 0. $$

Using Macaulay2, we managed to show that the variety is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$:

```
Macaulay2, version 1.22
with packages: ConwayPolynomials, Elimination, IntegralClosure, InverseSystems,
               Isomorphism, LLLBases, MinimalPrimes, OnlineLookup,
               PrimaryDecomposition, ReesAlgebra, Saturation, TangentCone

i1 : R = QQ[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5]

o1 = R

o1 : PolynomialRing

i2 : q = x3^2 + 2*x1*x4 - 4*x2*x4 +2*x2*x5 - 4*x1*x5

       2
o2 = x3  + 2x1*x4 - 4x2*x4 - 4x1*x5 + 2x2*x5

o2 : R

i3 : g = x4*(x1^2 - 2*x2^2) + x5*(x2^2 - 2*x1^2)

       2        2        2       2
o3 = x1 x4 - 2x2 x4 - 2x1 x5 + x2 x5

o3 : R

i4 : I = ideal(q, g)

              2                                        2        2        2    
o4 = ideal (x3  + 2x1*x4 - 4x2*x4 - 4x1*x5 + 2x2*x5, x1 x4 - 2x2 x4 - 2x1 x5 +
     ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
       2
     x2 x5)

o4 : Ideal of R

i5 : primaryDecomposition I

               2                                        2        2        2    
o5 = {ideal (x3  + 2x1*x4 - 4x2*x4 - 4x1*x5 + 2x2*x5, x1 x4 - 2x2 x4 - 2x1 x5 +
     ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
       2
     x2 x5)}

o5 : List

i6 : isPrimary I

o6 = true

i7 : isPrime I

o7 = true
```

Is there any possibility to see if the surface $\Sigma$ is irreducible over $\mathbb C$?

Comment: Note that your surface has a rational point (eg (0:0:0:1:1). Thus it is geometrically connected (hence connected over the complex numbers). Does your surface happen to be nonsingular or just normal? If so, it is geometrically irreducible. Actually, it suffices to check smoothness at some rational point if I recall correctly

Comment: Intriguing equations. Where do they come from?

Comment: I think the OP is thinking of some specific K3 surface or a degeneration of (2,3)-K3 surfaces.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Hi Ariyan, thank you for your comments. I do like your idea to check the geometrical irreducibility by looking at the rational point. But I don't think the surface $\Sigma$ is normal since it is singular at the line $(0: 0: 0: s: t)$.

Comment: @CraniumClamp Thank you for your comments. Indeed, this variety comes from the degeneration of a family of (2,3)-surfaces. I'm looking at a particular family of nodal cubic fourfolds  and the surface I'm considering is the surface of lines on the cubic fourfold passing through the nodal point. I want to check that for the general fibre in this particular family, the surface of lines passing through the nodal point is irreducible. I think it suffices to check for one fibre. The surface in OP is such a surface which is relatively easy to find the equations.

Comment: @Libli Hi Libli, this surface is the surface of lines passing through a nodal point in a particular nodal cubic fourfold. I'm looking at a particular family of nodal cubic fourfolds and I want to check that for the general fibre in this particular family, the surface of lines passing through the nodal point is irreducible.

Comment: @PènePapin I agree that your surface is singular along that line (hence not normal); I didn't do the calculation last night when I wrote the comment.  However, my suggestion stands: it might be worth looking for other *smooth* rational points. What about the line (s:t:0:0:0)?  Although I didn't carefully do the computation, there seem to be smooth points on that line (in which case you can conclude that your surface is geometrically integral).

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Hi Ariyan, thank you for your comments. But I'm not sure I understand correctly the idea. How the existence of a line of smooth points would imply the geometric irreducibility? Thank you in advance for your further indications.

Comment: @PènePapin I am using the following fact: Let X be a connected variety over a field $k$.  If $X(k)$ is non-empty, then $X$ is geometrically connected. This immediately implies that your surface is geometrically connected. But, since you want $X$ to be geometrically irreducible we have to work a bit harder. See next comment.

Comment: @PènePapin If $X$ is a nonsingular connected variety over a field $k$ of characteristic zero and $X(k)$ is nonempty, then $X$ is in fact geometrically irreducible. This is because $X_{\overline{k}}$ is connected (see previous comment) and nonsingular (because $k$ is perfect). Now use that a nonsingular connected variety is irreducible.

Comment: @PènePapin The question is now how to apply this to your situation. Let $S$ be your surface. Let $X$ be its smooth locus (the open subset of nonsingular points). This is a dense open. By the fact that $S$ is irreducible, the variety $X$ is irreducible (a nonempty open of an irreducible scheme is irreducible). Now, $X$ is a nonsingular connected variety and, as I said above, it seems to have a $k$-point. (Of course, $k=\mathbb{Q}$ in your situation.) Caution: I didn't check that there is a  $\mathbb{Q}$-point $(s:t:0:0:0)$ lying in $X$, but this should be relatively simple to achieve. Cont'd...

Comment: So, we conclude that $X_{\overline{k}}$ is irreducible. But it is dense in $S_{\overline{k}}$. Thus, the latter is irreducible.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Hi Ariyan, thank you so much for your nice argument and for your patient proof. Let's take it as an answer!

Comment: @PènePapin We are almost there. There is still one thing left to check. Namely,  can you check whether one of the points $(s:t:0:0:0)$ is nonsingular? To do so, write down the Jacobian matrix and check that it has rank two.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Hi Ariyan, thanks for following up. Indeed, I checked the nonsingularity yesterday and the result was as expected. The surface is nonsingular along $(s: t: 0: 0: 0)$ unless $s=0$ or $t=0$ or $s=t$ so your argument was perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me explain how to show that the projective surface $\Sigma$ is geometrically irreducible (see also the comments above).

First, we know that $\Sigma$ is irreducible (this was checked by the OP).

Also, a routine calculation should reveal that the point $(1:2:0:0:0)$ is nonsingular (the OP also checked this).

As the point (1:2:0:0:0) is obviously  $\mathbb{Q}$-rational, it follows from the following lemma that $\Sigma$ is geometrically irreducible (i.e., $\Sigma_{\mathbb{C}}$ is irreducible).

> > Lemma. Let $X$ be an irreducible finite type scheme over a field $k$. Suppose that there is a point $P\in X(k)$ such that $X$ is smooth at $P$. Then $X$ is geometrically irreducible.

Proof. Let $S\subset X$ be the smooth locus of $X$. Note that $S$ is a dense open subscheme. (It is always open. Density follows from the fact that it is non-empty and that $X$ is irreducible: any non-empty open of an irreducible scheme is dense.) Since $S$ is a dense open of an irreducible scheme, it is itself irreducible. Now, by assumption $S(k)\neq \emptyset$. Therefore, $S$ is geometrically connected. (To see this, use that Galois action of the absolute Galois group permutes the connected components of $S_{\overline{k}}$, but fixes $P$.) Since $S$ is smooth and geometrically connected, it is geometrically irreducible. It follows that $S_{\overline{k}}$ is an integral dense open subscheme of $X_{\overline{k}}$. Thus $X$ is geometrically irreducible. QED

Comment: So in the general case (say if you cannot find a $\mathbb Q$-rational point), you just have to find a number field $K$ where $X$ has a smooth point, and then you are reduced to showing that $X$ is irreducible over $K$ -- is that right?

Comment: Yes, that’s right.